# Count the character of file name and rename

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os
import glob
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory


fileDir = askdirectory()
print(fileDir)
#newfileDir=fileDir.replace('/','\\')

files =  glob.glob("*.ac3")
print files

cnt = 0
for f in files:
   if len(f) < 3 + 4:
      os.rename(f, str(cnt)+f)
      cnt += 1
      print("renamed " + f)
```

I need to count the character length of a file name less than 3 character and rename the file name to numeric.

[Here is error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3epXg.png)

Comment: what is a ? what is files ? what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I just ran your code. Works perfectly.

Comment: i have uploaded my error image in this page.Please clarify if any issue availed

Comment: use `os.chdir(fileDir)` before `glob.glob`

Comment: also tried on windows. Works for me. Try to update to python 2.7, as you said in your question (here you use 2.6)

Comment: I have done with python 2.7 only.

Comment: The screenshot tells otherwise. First line: "Python 2.6 ..."

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.I have installed python2.6 & 2.7.but run code with 2.6.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Now code working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import glob
import os

files =  glob.glob("*.ac3")

cnt = 0
for f in files:
   if len(f) < 3 + 4: # 4 is the length of the extension ".ac3"
      os.rename(f, str(cnt)+f)
      cnt += 1
      print("renamed " + f)
```

Comment: Actually i need to check  if file name contains less than 3 character , and rename it to my new name.Please share an example for guidance.

Comment: Updated my code.There  " files = total files ends with '.ac3' ".Then files will assigned for 'a'.

Comment: I faced this error.      os.rename(f, str(cnt) +f)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Please paste your code here again. The code works for me.